# garbage value from function in c

Tags: c, pointers, struct

this is a struct in my code

```
struct custDetail
{
    int reservationID;
    char *name;
    int year;
    int month;
    int mday;
    int hour;
    char *departurePoint;
    char *destination;
    char *seatType;
    char *seat;
    float price;
    int airlineID;
};
```

this is one of my function

```
void purchaseBusiness();

void purchaseBusiness()
{
    struct custDetail detail = { 0 };
    detail.seatType = "Business";
    detail = promptDetail(detail);
    //printf("\n%s", detail.name);
    //printf("\n%s %d", detail.name, detail.year);
    detail = assignSeat(detail);
    detail = confirmDetail(detail);
    printf("\n%s", detail.name);

    printf("\nBooking success");

    displayToFile(detail);

    return;
}
```

this is one the function called in function above

```
struct custDetail promptDetail(struct custDetail);

struct custDetail promptDetail(struct custDetail detail)
{
char name[100];
int flight, departTime;
time_t difference;

printf("\nEnter your name: ");
scanf("%s", name);
detail.name = name;

do
{
    printf("\nChoose your flight");
    printf("\nPress 1 - KUL to KCH");
    printf("\nPress 2 - KCH to KUL");
    scanf("%d", &flight);
    switch (flight)
    {
    case 1:
    {
              detail.departurePoint = "KUL";
              detail.destination = "KCH";
              printf("\nChoose your departure time");
              printf("\nPress 1 - 7:00");
              printf("\nPress 2 - 9:00");
              scanf("%d", &departTime);
              switch (departTime)
              {
              case 1: detail.hour = 7; break;
              case 2: detail.hour = 9; break;
              default: printf("\nPlease enter 1 or 2 only"); break;
              }
              break;
    }
    case 2:
    {
              detail.departurePoint = "KCH";
              detail.destination = "KUL";
              printf("\nChoose your departure time");
              printf("\nPress 1 - 19:00");
              printf("\nPress 2 - 21:00");
              scanf("%d", &departTime);
              switch (departTime)
              {
              case 1: detail.hour = 19; break;
              case 2: detail.hour = 21; break;
              default: printf("\nPlease enter 1 or 2 only"); break;
              }
              break;
    }
    default: printf("\nPlease enter 1 or 2 only");
    }
} while ((flight != 1 && flight != 2) || (departTime != 1 && departTime != 
2));

do
{
    printf("\nEnter the flight date (dd/mm/yyyy)");
    printf("\n30 days and above 10%% discount");
    printf("\n90 days and above 15%% discount");
    scanf("%d%*c%d%*c%d", &detail.mday, &detail.month, &detail.year);
    if (detail.year > 0 && detail.month > 0 && detail.month <= 12 && detail.mday > 0 && detail.mday <= 31)
    {
        difference = checkDate(detail.year, detail.month, detail.mday, detail.hour);
        if (difference < 0)
        {
            printf("\nPlease enter valid date");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter valid date");
        difference = -1;
    }
} while (difference < 0);
return detail;
}
```

input for name is: testing

the output at printf("\n%s", detail.name) is

> testing

and the output at printf("\n%s %d", detail.name, detail.year) will be garbage value.

why the detail.name returned a garbage value? and at the end comes out with different garbage value when the struct custDetail go on pass through all the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets take a look at these lines from your `promptDetail` function:

```
char name[100];
detail.name = name;
```

The first line above defined `name` as an array within the scope of the `promptDetail` function. Its life-time ends with the end of the `promptDetail` function.

The second line makes `detail.name` point to the first element of `name`.

That means once the function `promptDetail` and the `name` array (in a way) cease to exist, that pointer will no longer be valid. Attempting to dereference that pointer (like what happens if you print the "string" it's supposedly point to) will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Answer (score 1):

In your code

```
char name[100];
```

is local to the function `promptDetail()` and have automatic storage duration.

Inside the function, you use the struct member `name` to hold the address of the array

```
detail.name = name;
```

and later, upon returning from the function, you try to use the content present in that address.

Whereas, in reality, the array being a local array with automatic storage duration, reaches end of it's lifetime and after returning from the function call, inside the caller, the address is not *valid* anymore. Hence, you access an invalid memory and invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Seeing some garbage value is just another notion of the undefined behavior.

**Solution**: You have to either

- Make the local array have `static` storage duration, so as the lifetime of the array is till end of the program (i.e., the address remain valid after returning from the function call)
- use a pointer, call memory allocator functions to allocate memory and use that memory to store the value. Then, in the caller, once you're done using the value you have to `free()` the previously allocated memory.
- use an array as the member variable, instead of a pointer. You can then, scan and put the value in the array member, and use it in the caller.